# how to get values of same name of text boxes in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function ($) {
        $(function () {

       var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
                var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-   
       group'); 
       var $formGroupClone = $formGroup.clone();


       $(this)
                    .toggleClass('btn-default btn-add btn-danger btn-
       remove')
                    .html('–');

                $formGroupClone.find('input').val('');
                $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);

                var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-
              group:last');

                if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') <= 
              countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                    $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', 
               true);

      }
            };



         var removeFormGroup = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var $formGroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
                var $multipleFormGroup = $formGroup.closest('.multiple-form-
              group');

                var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-
               group:last');
                if ($multipleFormGroup.data('max') >= 
           countFormGroup($multipleFormGroup)) {
                    $lastFormGroupLast.find('.btn-add').attr('disabled', 
          false);
                }

                $formGroup.remove();
            };

            var countFormGroup = function ($form) {
                return $form.find('.form-group').length;
            };

            $(document).on('click', '.btn-add', addFormGroup);
            $(document).on('click', '.btn-remove', removeFormGroup);

        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This is my web page.

```
<body>
 <form runat ="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddEmail" name="multipleEmail[]"  class="form-control"    
  runat="server" Width="355px" AutoPostBack="true" 
  OnTextChanged="txtFirstName_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
 <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-add">
    +
  </button>
  </span>
```

This is my code. I try to code in onclick method but in couldn't work. All the values which is entered in textboxes will saved in one cell in table. I want to save the data row by row.

can you suggest any solution for this problem?

I have no idea about above java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking but here's a simple way to save data from a TextBox. Are you trying to save all the data inside Javascript then save it later by sending it to the server?

```
<body>
<form runat ="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddEmail" name="multipleEmail[]"  class="form-control"    
 runat="server" Width="355px" ></asp:TextBox>
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-add" onclick="SaveStuff">Add</button>
</span>

public void SaveStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveToDataBase(txtAddEmail.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. but   http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multiple-fields-contact-form . See this link you will get an idea what I am asking. when clicking the green button it will create new textboxes with the same name. After submitted the values into database it save all the values in one cell. I want to save the values row by row.

Comment: Ah, if that's the case, then I'd suggest a 'Save' button on the page which does an ajax postback to the server with a javascript array of all the numbers. Once you get the numbers in an array then you can just save them as separate rows.